# How to detect whether the 'new' keyword was used?

Tags: javascript

Is this particularly robust (to try and detect whether the 'new' keyword was used to create an object)?

```
this.constructor.toString().indexOf('window') === -1
```

Bear in mind I don't care too much about ancient browsers like IE6/7/8.

Comment: From inside the constructor function?

Comment: if(this===window) alert("wohoo. Im global!");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not only not robust, it's incorrect. It looks for the characters `"window"` anywhere in the constructor function, which gives both false positives (you can call a function without `new` without `"window"` appearing in it anywhere) and false negatives (just because the constructor contains `"window"`, that doesn't mean it wasn't called with `new`).

In ES5 and earlier, you can't be **absolutely sure** `new` was used at all, but you can be close enough with:

```
if (this instanceof TheConstructorName) {
    // Yes, `new` was probably used
}
```

...but that can be defeated:

```
var f = new TheConstructorName(); // Really called with `new`
TheConstructorName.call(f);       // Tricks it
```

If you use strict mode, `this` will be `undefined` if someone just does `TheConstructorName()`, but you can't just rely on `this` being `undefined`, because someone could do `TheConstructorName.call({})` or even `var o = {c: TheConstructorName}; o.c();`, either of which set `this` to a value other than `undefined`, even in strict mode.

In ES2015+, you can be completely sure by looking at [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target):

```
if (new.target) {
    // Yes, `new` was used
}
```

You don't need to do that if you use `class` syntax, though; constructors created with `class` *can't* be called without `new` (directly or indirectly as `super`).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of solutions to check this...

### ECMAScript 5

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
    throw new Error('Oops!');
  }

  console.log('OK');
}

new Foo(); // OK
Foo(); // Error
```

```js
function Foo() {
  if (this.constructor !== Foo) {
    throw new Error('Oops!');
  }

  console.log('OK');
}

new Foo(); // OK
Foo(); // Error
```

### ECMAScript 6

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) {
    throw new Error('Oops!');
  }

  console.log('OK');
}

new Foo(); // OK
Foo(); // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

As was previously mentioned, `instanceof` is a pretty good way to detect whether the `new` keyword was used. Here is some code you can use in case someone forgets the `new` keyword, so they don't get weird results:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo(bar)
    }

    this.bar = bar
    return this
}

new Foo(1, 2) // OK
Foo(3, 4) // OK
```